# What is the difference between Django and Python?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking at a job possibility that has a need for both Django and Python. I have some experience with Python but none with Django, nor do I know precisely what Django is. Can someone please explain the difference between Django and Python, how they are related and what they are used for?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_(web_framework)

Comment: Django is a Python package :P

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: Wrong question to ask. Django is a framework built on top of Python. So, end of the day both are Python code. Just that Django has some utility methods that can come in handy

Answer (score 6):

Python is a programming language. Django is a web framework built using Python, designed to simplify the creation of websites. It provides a set of common functionality to reduce the amount of trivial code that you need to write.

Django provides:

- An administration panel
- A database modeling layer
- A templating system
- Form generation and validation.

and other common functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great overview of the idea to answer your question.
http://www.ehow.com/info_8450257_difference-python-django.html

Essentially Django is a web-framework that is built using Python, the programming language. Python is the language used to program in, and Django is a framework that helps abstract away and ease some of the routine tasks that webmasters encounter often.